# Add information to a question

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

What is the way to add some important information to a question if you have too little reputation for a comment, and the answer section is blocked?

Comment: Add information to a question you are not the author of? And how did you come about this information? Did the OP offered it via comments?

Comment: Regardless, answers are for answering, not for adding information to questions.

Comment: That is pretty difficult to do.  Your edit will be reviewed because you don't have enough rep yet, sweeping changes to questions are very rarely approved.  If you need to do this because you have the same question then consider just asking it yourself.  Do mention that you saw that other one or you'll risk getting it closed as a dup.  Somebody ought to add some info to this question :)

Comment: @yivi I have the same proplem and I found a small step to the solution. I get the advice to put this information in the comments or in an answer (but this wasn't possible).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. I will think about open a own question with a link to the closed one.

Comment: Just be sure to avoid whatever problem got the other question closed.

Comment: @BSMP The other question was only a stacktrace without any idea why this problems exsits, any possibily to reproduce the problem or clear problem statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

If the question is your own, you can add a comment with the account from which you posted it. And you can edit the question.

If the question is not your own, and it was closed... too bad. It was closed because we don't want it to be answered.

We have a reputation requirement for commenting, to prevent nonsense comments, spam and pointless discussion.

After you have gained 50 points, you are considered to understand the system well enough to write useful comments.

Whether that threshold is at the right value, is something one can debate; but we do have that threshold for a reason.

There are a few things you could do, if you believe you really have something to add.

- Join a chat where the issue is relevant. This only takes 20 points, and if there is a chatroom where users will find your insight useful, someone might be able to post it as a comment on your behalf.
- Suggest an edit the question. I do **NOT** recommend this, as an edit adding information will likely be rejected. But, it would get the information on the system, and to the attention of the reviewers... who *might* just add it to the question as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 20 points are more than I have. As you said, the second proposal did not work.